# How to use ng-repeat without creating a new scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ng-repeat to place multiple checkbox buttons from the [angular-ui-bootstrap library](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) inside of a btn-group. The angular documentation says that [`each template instance gets its own scope`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat). I believe that the following `ng-repeat` code fails to work because it does not use the same scope as the parent controller, and can therefore not access `$scope.zones`.

**QUESTION:** Can I use `ng-repeat` in the context of the same original `$scope`? If so, what issues might I run into and what other ways are there for me to make this work correctly?

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="(zone, action) in zones track by $index" btn-checkbox ng-model="zones['{{zone}}'])"> Zone - {{zone}}</div>
```

**Working Version**

```
<div btn-checkbox="btn-checkbox" ng-model="zones['one']" class="btn btn-primary">Zone 1</div>
<div btn-checkbox="btn-checkbox" ng-model="zones['two']" class="btn btn-primary">Zone 2</div>
<div btn-checkbox="btn-checkbox" ng-model="zones['three']" class="btn btn-primary">Zone 3 </div>
<div btn-checkbox="btn-checkbox" ng-model="zones['goal']" class="btn btn-primary">Goalie Zone </div>
```

**JS (inside the controller)**

```
/*  Zones  */
$scope.zones = {
  'one': false,
  'two': false,
  'three': false,
  'goal': false
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: use the $parent directive to keep your scope at the same level as your parent item (not the recommended way); or use a *model.property* style on the `ngModel` attribute.

Where I was having an issue recently was that I wanted to assign the ngModel attribute without a model declaration:

```
<input type="text" id="{{question.id}}" ng-model="Answer"/>
```

When I changed it to this, everything worked:

```
<input type="text" id="{{question.id}}" ng-model="question.Answer"/>
```

Using the dot notation will also tell Angular where the appropriate scope is.

**UPDATE**

You may have to build a wrapper around your array. In your controller, change the declaration/assignment to this:

```
$scope.model.zones = { 'one': false,
                       'two': false,
                       'three': false,
                       'goal': false };
```

Then change your ngModel references in the example `div`s to `model.zones['one']`.

Comment: I'm using the second method, but I'm trying to set the property dynamically based on the keys in `$scope.zones`. See the code.

Comment: Then your next option is to create a wrapper around zones so that you can use the dot notation.

Comment: The wrapper idea did work, but I had to implement it a different way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so like +Adam Zuckerman said, I needed a wrapper around my `$scope.zones` object, but I had to turn it into an array, which allowed me to access the model with the `$index` property.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="zone in zones track by $index" btn-checkbox ng-model="zones[$index].action" class="btn btn-primary">Zone - {{zone.name}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
/*  Zones  */
$scope.zones = [
  {
    name: 'one',
    action: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'two',
    action: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'three',
    action: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'goal',
    action:  false
  }
];
```

Comment: Once you have an array of objects to repeat over, you can just bind `ng-model` to `zone.action` directly instead of using the `$index`.